# Pandas to drop a specific value

Tags: python, pandas

```
Name,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020
ABBOTSFORD,652000,736000,730000,714000,792500,862500,925000,1187500,1280000,1192500,1030000,1150000
ABERFELDIE,786500,1046500,994000,852500,947500,1045000,1207500,1300000,1453000,1500000,1390000,1592500
AINTREE,-,-,-,-,-,-,680500,640000,571500,580000,610000,675000
AVONSLEIGH,309000,321500,385500,345000,420000,355000,397500,501000,562000,540000,532500,NA
```

If I have a list of names that and years like the one above, how could I use pandas to drop the rows that have '-'? I already have a code that drops the NA rows but I'm not sure how to do it for the '-'?

```
df = pd.read_csv('modified_data.csv')
df = df.dropna() #This drops the NA
df = df[df.2009 != "-"] #This is the one that doesn't work

print(df)
```

Comment: Try `df['2009']` instead of `df.2009`. In Python it's not allowed to have variable names starting with digits.

Comment: You *should* actually always use `df['col']` and never `df.col`, this prevents many mistakes/errors.

Comment: Using` df = df.loc[df['2009'] != "-"] ` works but when I do it for the rest of the years, it gives an error, which I linked below

Answer (score 1):

use proper column name:

```
df = df.loc[df['2009'] != "-"]
```

instead of `df.2009`

Comment: Thank you, do I use this code for the rest of the other years too?ie

df = df.loc[df['2009'] != "-"]


df = df.loc[df['2010'] != "-"]
...

Comment: if your intention is to remove any rows that has "-", then you can use `df = df.replace('-', np.Nan)` and simply use dropna after that.

Comment: Nevermind. There's an error when I try to do it, do you know how to fix this?

/opt/python-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py:792: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  result = getattr(x, name)(y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 12, in <module>
    df = df.loc[df['2017'] != "-"]

Comment: File "/opt/python-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 855, in wrapper
    res = na_op(values, other)
  File "/opt/python-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 794, in na_op
    raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")
TypeError: invalid type comparison

Comment: @ user96564. Thanks for the idea but it doesn't work for me. I'm assuming that you need to import numpy as np right? This is the error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 4, in <module>
    df = df.replace('-', np.Nan)
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'Nan'

Comment: @NLT yes you need to import numpy. that np.nan is from numpy.

Comment: @ user96564 I did but it gives out the error message above

Comment: @NLT, I am not sure what could go wrong there unless there is something else you are doing wrong.  df.replace or loc with 2017, etc should work.